# Problems with weird edges after Subdviding/Smoothing surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, 3d-view, sculpting

I am modelling my first blender character ever. I modeled one side, then symmetrized it and merged the two symmetrical sides together.

When adding the subdivishion Surface modifier and/or adding the smoothing Surface, I cannot get this edge to be smooth as the others. It forms into a sharp line all along my mesh.

I tried deleting doubles using *Merge by distance* and I tried smoothing it in sculpt mode. I tried deleting the edge by combining the two faces into one, but that just made two weird lines instead of one.

[My blender file](https://we.tl/t-yjHhCrJHaV). I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: While sharing blend files is helpful, they should be a last resort. [Please post screenshots of the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) so we can see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ur Problem is the face orientation. If u Turn on "Face Orientation" on and check, u can clearly see half of ur face is its back facing outside (Red is the back of the face, Blue is the front of the face. Generally, u shoud have all faces blue)
[image]

select all ur faces and type F3, search for "recalculate outside" to correct ur wrong facing direction. then it should smooth properly
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! Wow this was huge a huge help!!

Comment: Wish u happy blendering

Comment: Oh, I don't forget to set my answer to "Accepted", to close ur question. And I will get a credit for it